# Central Limit Theorem: Is the likelihood of obtaining some sample mean exact when n is not infinity?

Tags: sampling, central-limit-theorem, small-sample, population, frequentist

The central limit theorem states:

$$ \lim _{n\to \infty}{\sqrt{n}}{\left({\frac {{\bar {X}}_{n}-\mu }{\sigma }}\right)} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1) $$

Which means if I ran an infinite number of experiments, I could calculate the likelihood of any interval of sample means.

However, if I have a finite sample (size *n*), doesn't that introduce some error in any likelihood that I calculate?, since smaller sample sizes will further away from the normal distribution expected by the CLT?

So, if I integrate over some interval of sample means, rather than saying, "here's the exact likelihood of obtaining this interval of sample means", I should instead be saying: "here's the exact likelihood plus whatever error is introduced by having a finite *n*"?

Comment: If the $X_i$ are iid normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ then ${\sqrt{n}}{\left({\frac {{\bar {X}}_{n}-\mu }{\sigma }}\right)} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ without any need for a limit, whether $n=1$ or some higher number.  The error for other distributions is more that they are not normal distributions, and the size of the error in the probability for a particular interval will also depend on what the original distribution is and which interval.

Comment: got it; so that would make it difficult to quantify _exactly_ how much "extra error" there is when $ X_i $ is _**not**_ normally distribution; but it's still accurate to say that some extra error exists?